# 'RLMException', reason: 'Opening Realm files of format version 11 is not supported by this version of Realm'

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to login into realm but it keeps throwing the RLMException error.

This my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'App' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for App
pod 'RealmSwift'

target 'AppUITests' do
  # Pods for testing
end

end
```

This is the login function

```
func login(){
    
    let usernameCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username: "user", password: "password")
    // Create the configuration
    let syncServerURL = URL(string: "realms://jaffjf.faf.cloud.realm.io/default")!
    SyncUser.logIn(with: usernameCredentials, server: syncServerURL) { user, error in
            if let user = user {
                print("logged in",user)
                 let config = user.configuration(realmURL: syncServerURL);

            // Open the remote Realm
            let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
          
            
              Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config) { realm, error in
                        if let realm = realm {
                          
                            let results = realm.objects(Temp.self)
                            print("This is the results......", results)
             
           
                        } else if let error = error {
                        
                            print("No realm found....")
                        }
                    }
            
        } else if let error = error {
            
        }
    }
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Opening Realm files of format version 11 is not supported by this version of Realm'
> *** First throw call stack:

what is causing the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Realm at all but this error message is quite meaningful: *The format of the file is not supported by the version you are using.*

Comment: Did you update your server-side Realm version, but not the client side one? It seems the version of your synced Realm file is newer than the one your Realm-swift version supports.

Comment: Check the [release notes](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/releases) for all of the releases from 5.0.0 and forward as Realm Studio will make changes to your Realms and there are some API version changes as well.

Answer (score 2):

This error indicates you need to be using Realm Cocoa 5.4.x, at this moment in time the latest version is 5.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Just open finder of file path and remove realm files.
Then build you project again.

I resolved same problem this way.

Comment: Please clarify process. I don't understand what you did